# displaying php content in JavaScript new window

Tags: php, javascript

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
$output = <<<BLOCK

    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Preview!</title>

            <script type="text/javascrit">
                var content = $data;
            </script> 

        </head>
        <body>
            <a href="" onclick="preview()">Click Me!</a>
            <script type="text/javascript"> 
                function preview(){
                    var preview = window.open('','preview','scrollbars=1,height=500,width=500,resizable=1');
                    preview.document.open();
                    preview.document.write(content);
                    preview.document.close(); 

                }
            </script> 
        </body>
    </html>     
BLOCK;
echo $output;
```

$data contains a full html document generated by the php script.

This doesn't seem to work, but I think you can get the idea what I'm trying to do.

Comment: "javascrit" -> "javascript", but I doubt that that's your problem. "Doesn't [seem to] work" is a phrase that should be banned at SO, because it means so little. If it didn't work, **what did happen**?

Comment: A new window will pop up, the address is about:blank, the title is untitled, and the content is blank.   

- What's in $data is just plain html, nothing fancy.

Answer (score 0):

"data" is generated from another script...can we see it?
UPDATED:
You cant pass "content" from the **head** to the **body** like that, it is **null** , try as a given parameter to the function preview.
Try accessing it where you do the OPEN().

Or store "data" in a hidden div or get it via AJAX(preferably).
content2=null;
content="asdsadas";

```
$data="asdsadas";
$output = "
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Preview!</title>

            <script type=\"text/javascript\">
                var content2 = '".$data."'
            </script> 

        </head>
        <body>
            <a href=\"\" onclick=\"preview()\">Click Me!</a>
            <script type=\"text/javascript\"> 
                function preview(){
                var content = '".$data."'
                    var preview = window.open('','preview','scrollbars=1,height=500,width=500,resizable=1');
                    preview.document.open();
                    preview.document.write(content);
            preview.document.write(content2);
                    preview.document.close(); 

                }
            </script> 
        </body>
    </html>";
echo $output;
```

Comment: Hi KA_lin, you've been very helpful, i'd like to rate you up on that alone if that is permitted.  

I solved my problem in a very different manner.

In your example, passing a "plain" string in didn't cause any problems.  
It was when I tried to pass in some html tags/content that I started getting problems-- I had over 200 lines of html content.  
some errors that I got were, unterminated string literal, undefined function, and syntax error. (I prob should have mentioned these earlier)

Comment: I did two things to solve my problem: 

1. broke the string down into an array 
2. ran addslahses on each array value.  
I then used document.write to output each element of the array.

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Wee have to know what does $data contains, but you certainly have to escape quotes or specials chars ...